# Better approach to share a variable between components in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am creating an app using react-native and socket.io. Once connected with socket.io using `io.connect(...)` I need to save a variable with socket client that can be used in any component.

But the problems are:

1 - I am using react-navigation, so I can't pass as a property from component because the connection is not made in the navigator root, it's being made inside a child scree

2 - I can't pass as navigation parameter using `this.props.navigation.navigate(route, {socketIo})` because it is a circular object, and the JSON.stringify  inside react-navigation module throws an error trying to deal with the data

3 - I can't make a module and import it in other files, once it will generate multiple connections

The workaround that solved my problem was to set a global variable like this:

`global.socket = io.connect(...)`

But while googling I found many people saying it is not a good approach. Is there any way better to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a particular case to share variables and methods across the react native application, because you need to share a *socket* connection with private methods to emit and receive events, and not share variables only.

In this case, Redux is not enough. I solve that by creating a navigator container using a new [StackNavigator](https://gist.github.com/danielfeelfine/9d53bf446c65c16f258e49174a8aa926#file-socketnavigator-js), handler the *socket* connection and events in this container and manage actions by Redux. Eg.: If you need to dispatch an event in some screen, you can dispatch that using Redux and listen in [SocketContainer](https://gist.github.com/danielfeelfine/9d53bf446c65c16f258e49174a8aa926#file-socketcontainer-js) and then execute the IO operation.

Additionally, I create a Polyfill, because the socket implementation in React Native has the [userAgent](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*Y-lk0rVlht9AMm26Ulp4OQ.png) error. You can read more about in [this article](https://medium.com/@A7medAshraff/how-to-use-socket-io-with-react-native-app-80bb3f168405).

The complete example of my implementation can be [found here](https://gist.github.com/danielfeelfine/9d53bf446c65c16f258e49174a8aa926).

Comment: Thank for your answer. Use a component is a good idea and worked fine for me

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a use case for redux. Redux allows you share data amongst all your components.